# Is there any way to prevent Path Traversal in this code?

Tags: php, html, security

I'm trying to prevent people to use path traversal on some code. I need to do this for an assigment I've been stuck on for too long. After testing the redirect I also have to check if the page "welkom'' has stayed the same.

```
$pagedir = "pages";

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    header("Location: ?page=welkom");
    exit;
}

$page = $_GET['page'];

if (file_exists("$pagedir/$page")) {
    print file_get_contents("$pagedir/$page");
}
```

Comment: Hi, most people in here think you should do your own homework. I must say it is refreshingly honest you say so yourself beforehand you have this as homework. :-)

Comment: Apply `realpath`, and then check if the result is still within your allowed “base” path.